# Is __pycache__ crossplatform?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a folder of files `/foo`. This folder gets included as package_data in the `setup.py` for my Python package. When someone `pip install`'s my package, they're able to download `/foo` to their computer.

I've noticed though that when this happens, a `__pycache__` folder gets included for all the `*.py` files in `/foo`. I'm not sure if this is created when my wheel is created, or when it's installed. I'm assuming it's during wheel creation though.

Since my package should work on windows/osx/linux, will things break because of the `__pycache__` folder? Is it platform specific, or will it work cross platform? Or does the folder get created during wheel installation and it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__pycache__` is usually generated on the fly at the point the package is installed, unless you have accidentally included it in your project (in which case it is best to remove it). For the full spec, see [PEP3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/).

The compiled code is designed to fail safe. That is, if it exists but isn't compiled for your OS/architecture, then it should be ignored.